# Removing reflection/shade

Tags: texturing, objects, light

How should I remove the shade from that part of object?I've connected 2 edges, and that's how I got that part, but the shade annoys me, and I want it to delete. How can I do that?[image: Photo]

Answer (score 2):

At its simplest, that's probably selecting the face in Edit Mode (Face), and from the right-click menu, selecting 'Shade Flat'.